# Page - specific Datepicker config in jcalendar.tpl

Tags: best-practice, dates

How does one add a default value in one of Datepicker fields while adding or editing Relationship? For example, set today's date as a start date at Enabled checkbox check and as the end date if un-checked.  Should it be a custom piece of jQuery code or it's better to alter jcalendar.tpl? If latter, how one defines "Add/Edit Relationship" modal frame has been triggered and not, say, "Add/Edit Membership?" one.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a datepicker's default value in the `setDefaultValues()` method of the form.  Here is a snippet of code that sets a date to today if none exists, and to a saved date if it does:

```
    if (empty($data['thank_you_date'])) {
      $defaultValues['thank_you_date'] = date('Y-m-d');
    } else {
      $defaultValues['thank_you_date'] = $data['thank_you_date'];
    }
```